# Android view animation: replacing view by itself

Tags: android, animation

In my android app, I have a notion of "trails": a sequence of objects that the user can navigate.  The same view, naturally, is used to display all objects, just updating components (texts, images, etc.) when the next object is to be shown.

Now, I want to animate the transition between objects: when the user navigates from an object to the next object, I want to use the slide animation from right to left (and the other way around).  The issue is that I don't have two views to animate between - only one view.  Therefore when I try to animate displaying this view (when the next object is to be loaded), the visible view disappears, I get a blank screen - and then the view slides in from the right.

What I want instead is to have the existing view to slide out and be replaced by a new view (same View but with different content) to slide in from the right.

How should I go about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution turned out to be very simple: ViewPager. I provide PageAdapter, which returns two similar views (same layout, different content) and ViewPager takes care of the rest. If I wanted to disable the swipe page changes, all I had to do is extend ViewPager, override onInterseptTouchListener and return false.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like a combination of [`LayoutTransition`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/LayoutTransition.html) and [`GestureDetector`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.html).  You might even a [`ViewFlipper`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper.html) in there too.

The LayoutTransition has an animation feature you might want to look into.

Comment: Yes, I was looking into LayoutTransition, but can't quite figure out how it would apply in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't been able to figure out how to use LayoutTransition in my case, so instead of having my View, I replaced it with ViewFlipper containing two copies of my View.  When I need to replace the view with another, I keep track of which of the two is currently displayed, then update the other off-screen and then use standard "slide-from-left" and "slide-from-right" animation with `showNext()`.  This is more complicated than I really wanted it to be and uses more memory, but it does the job.